# How can I get svelte to work with typescript using webpack 5?

Tags: typescript, webpack, svelte

I am trying to get typescript support added to my existing svelte project which is bundled and configured with webpack 5. I am unable to get the typescript compiler to work with `.svelte` components.

Specifically, if I have a `.svelte` component:

```
<script lang="ts">
    let s: number = "Super Component";
</script>
<section>
    I am a component: {s}
</section>
```

I expect the build to fail with a type error. However, it just keeps running without any acknowledgement of the types.

To reproduce this issue, you can download [this basic webpack svelte ts configuration](https://github.com/federico-paolillo/svelte-template-webpack-typescript) and add an incorrect type inside a svelte component. For example, `const a: string = 2`

Notice that running `npm run start` will run the project without issue. If you add an incorrect type to `main.ts`, the compiler will correctly throw an error. However, if you add an incorrect type to `App.svelte`, absolutely nothing happens. I do not know why tsc is not catching the error.

If anyone has a helpful idea on how to enforce typescript inside the svelte component `<script lang="ts">...</script>` tags, I would appreciate it. Thanks